# How to add an id to my background?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, background, ionic3, background-image

I use ionic 3.
How to add an id to my background?

```css
ion-content {
        background-image: url('../assets/imgs/back.png');
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;   }
```

Comment: You put an id on the element in the html, ie `id="someid"` or are you asking how to make an [ID css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)?

Comment: I tried but my background disappears, sorry I'm a beginner. 
Can you tell me what exactly I need to put?
(I ask how to make this background have an id.)

Comment: `<div id="someId" class="ion-content"></div>` Then you need a "." on your class selector `.ion-content { your styles } #someID { your styles }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is this?
.ion-content #someId {
        background-image: url('../assets/imgs/back.png');
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;   }

Comment: I do that but my background disappears completely.

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: @Alec The problem of ID is solved. But my background is not fixed, it moves ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you're a bit confused, in CSS classes and IDs both act as selectors and can both use the same CSS properties. Meaning it's not usually necessary to have both on an object. There is nothing wrong with having an ID and a class (or multiple classes) it's just not usually necessary.

See this example: https://codepen.io/samandalso/pen/zaPpve

In it we are using an ID and a class on the same div, but you could easily move all of the CSS rules to one or the other and get the same result. The last selector is a child selector, which is saying and div that is a child of a parent with the class "ion-content" give 100px of padding on all four sides and make the color red. Does that help?

```
/* Individual selectors */
#myID {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.ion-content {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x100) center center;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Child selector */

.ion-content div {
  color: red;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I see, but so I'm supposed to do that ( my background still doesn't appear whit this, still an error on my part?).

#back { 
background-size: 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; } 

.ion-content { 
background: url('../assets/imgs/back.png'); }

Comment: Could be the link to your bg image, or perhaps the div has no height or width so therefore the background isn't showing. Hard to say without seeing all of your code. You can use codepen or jsfiddle to post your code and share that here.